# wordpress woocommerce, showing a single specific product and its options on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

For a reference of the website i am developing you can view it here: http://prettyloxx.netii.net/

I am creating a ecommerce website using wordpress and woocommerce together in a theme 
that i added the woocommerce support to. it would's great but however i am a little stuck.

What i would like to do is to place a single specific product on the bottom of the homepage with its options.

So ideally, i would for example like to add a single product such as http://prettyloxx.netii.net/?product=wefts on the homepage after the homepage content, howevere without the product's description. So on the hompage the user would see the attributes and options as well as the product image at the bottom of the page, select them and then click on the checkout button directly from the homepage.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

You can add `[product id="99"]` or `[product sku="FOO"]` Shortcode for specific product to add your homepage. Or if you want feature products then woocommerce gives the shortcode `[featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]` for that. Hope those will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use Id of single woocoomerce product ,
[product id="42632 "] 
and for sku 
 [product sku="examplesku"]
and we can show products of a specific category 
[products columns="3" category="solar-lantern"]
In above shortcode just pass the slug of the category and products are shown of this specific category